# Can an SSD drive be used without a controller?

Tags: motherboard, ssd, controller

I read somewhere that an SSD can be attached to a motherboard using the PCI-Express bus without a controller. I am not sure what this means. If these are special kind of motherboards, what are some of these motherboards (brand name and model)?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably thinking about SSDs that use PCI Express instead of SATA interface. They can go on any motherboard (provided that there are PCI express slots) and, once system is booted, they behave just as standard disks.

Advantage to this approach is lowering latency and speed increase. Disadvantage is being unable to boot from such [device](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/1683/exclusive_look_at_fusion_io_iodrive_pcie_solid_state/index.html).

It happens that more modern variants of these [devices](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/2852/exclusive_review_of_photofast_s_g_monster_promise_1000mb_s_128gb_pcie_ssd/index.html) are bootable (they have integrated HDD controller).

Comment: So if the SSD is using PCI-E, the system can't boot from the SSD? That's not good. The whole point of using SSD was to put the OS and major apps on it.

Comment: @Tony It is not good for casual users. I've seen this used on database servers. OS was on SATA and database data was on PCI-E based SSDs.